# How to update ProgressBarDialog while copying file using Input/ output stream and a Handler Async Task deprecated in android 11

Tags: java, android

I am  new to Java and android development. I am using Storage access framework to let user  pick file then copy file to internal app storage.

I am not able to delete the original  file for api level 22 (lollipop).

I cannot understand how to update progressBarDialog's progress.

I am   using handler to do this in background as ASYNC TASK deprecated for android 11

```
final Intent data = resultData;
                final String typed = type;

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Uri uri = data.getData();
                        // get open stream for uri
                        // String result = moveSelectedFiles(uri, typed);
                        final int fileSize = getFileSize(uri);
                        Log.i(TAG, "file size: " + fileSize);


                        try {

                            InputStream input = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                            String fileName = uri2filename(uri);
                            String imageDestination = getContext().getFilesDir() + "/userData/" + typed;
                            File newFile = new File(imageDestination, fileName);
                            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                            OutputStream out = outStream;

                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            int read;

                            while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                                out.write(buffer, 0, read);

                            }
                            input.close();
                            out.flush();
                            out.close();
                            // getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(uri,null,null);


                            DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
                            //TODO: DELETE ORIGiNAL NOT WORKING IN ANDROID API 22 ( ERROR DELETE NOT SUPPORTED, SELECTING FILE FROM SYSTEM PICKER USING  Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);)

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }


                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                progressDialog.setMax(fileSize);
                                // progressDialog.setProgress();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();
```

Comment: If you have a working solution using `AsyncTask`, feel free to use it. Deprecation doesn't mean removal. `AsyncTask` will continue to work for a long time, it will just be crossed out in your IDE. You should not worry about the deprecation at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too have been thinking about how to handle the removal of `AsyncTask` in Android 11

One option I've seen is just to copy the Java code from Android's source in to your own project (As it is has a License that allows this). Of Course you then become responsible for maintaining the code from that point onwards.

I looked at Handlers and discounted the idea.

The other option that appealed to me and seemed simple enough was RxJava

Below is my first attempt at replicating an Asynctask for a progressBar in RxJava

MainActivity.java

```java
package com.test.rxjavaprogress;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.ObservableEmitter;
import io.reactivex.ObservableOnSubscribe;
import io.reactivex.Observer;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private Observable<Integer> observable;
    private Observer<Integer> observer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        observable = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Integer>() {
           @Override

           public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<Integer> e) throws Exception {
               // doInBackground
               for (int i=1; i<= 100; i++) {
                   Log.e(String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId()), "i: " + i);
                   e.onNext(i);
                   Thread.sleep(50);
               }
               e.onComplete();
           }
       }
        );


        observer = new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                // onPreExecute
                Log.e(String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId()), "onSubscribe: ");
                progressBar.setProgress(0);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer value) {
                // onProgressUpdate
                Log.e(String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId()), "onNext: " + value);
                progressBar.setProgress(value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.e(String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId()), "onError: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                // onPostExecute
                Log.e(String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId()), "onComplete: All Done!");
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        };
    }

    public void button(View view){
        Log.e(String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId()), "button: Clicked");
        // Start background task
        observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
                subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
                subscribe(observer);
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="button"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:max="100"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

App build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.rxjavaprogress"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.18'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

As you can see from LogCat

```
2020-02-24 16:36:55.372 5620-5620/com.test.rxjavaprogress E/2: button: Clicked
2020-02-24 16:36:55.421 5620-5620/com.test.rxjavaprogress E/2: onSubscribe: 
2020-02-24 16:36:55.428 5620-5696/com.test.rxjavaprogress E/278: i: 1
2020-02-24 16:36:55.433 5620-5620/com.test.rxjavaprogress E/2: onNext: 1
```

The "doInBackground" is on a different Thread to the UI thread.

This is not the most compact way of doing it, but is more verbose to help understanding.